# How can i filter a GET query from express server and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I want to create a GET route that get all my tasks but only the one with task_completed property boolean 'false'.

existing route:

```
router.get('/getalltasks', cors(), async(req, res) => {
Task.find(function(err, tasks) {

// if there is an error retrieving, send the error. 
                // nothing after res.send(err) will execute
if (err)
    res.send(err);


res.json(tasks); // return all tasks that are in JSON format 

  });
});
```

MongoosSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
task_name:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    unique: true,
},
task_category: String,
task_xpreward: Number,
task_completed: Boolean,
task_difficulty: Number,    //1 = Easy, 2 = Medium, 3 = Hard, 4 = Very Hard, 5 = Impossible
task_city : String,
});

 //sommige variabelen kunnen opgedeeld worden in 2de schema met relatie 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);
```

how can i implement this in the existing code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so if you want one task with `task_completed: false` property:

EDIT: catch errors:

```
router.get('/getalltasks', cors(), async(req, res) => {
let task;
try{
task = await Task.findOne({task_completed: false});
   }catche (e){
    console.log(`Err: ${e}`);
   }
 res.json(task);
}
```

and if you want all tasks with `task_completed: false`:

```
router.get('/getalltasks', cors(), async(req, res) => {
const tasks = await Task.find({task_completed: false});
res.json(tasks);
}
```

Comment: how can i add error handling to the Task.find because now if something goes wrong it does not give an error ofc , thank you for helping me